# Алгоритм расположения постов в Google+

Tags: алгоритм, google-plus, соцсети

Мне интересно, по какому алгоритму гугл+ разбивает новости на колонки? Поточнее, как мы знаем там 2 колонки. И некоторые новости попадают в правую колонку, некоторые в левую. По какому алгоритму это происходит? Или тупо одна новость идет в левую колонку, а другая в правую?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точного алгоритма не знаю, но готов предположить, ибо сам когда-то реализовывал подобное. Каждая новая запись помещается в колонку, имеющую на момент добавления наименьшую высоту. Таким образом, записи относительно равномерно распределяются по колонкам. Кстати, на более широких экранах (у меня 24") число колонок увеличивается до 3.

Comment: т.е мне поставить туда 2 блока-колонки и при каждом добавлении сравнить высоты блоков. Если B1 < B2, то новость помещается в блок B1. Так? Если так, то легко реализуемо :)

Comment: Да, вы всё правильно поняли.